# jQuery Sortable for combination of two different lists

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to combine two list for sorting which work like single list. My code is.

```
$(function () {
 $("#sortable").sortable({
     connectWith: "#sortable1"
 });

 $("#sortable1").sortable({
     connectWith: "#sortable"
 });

 $("#sortable,#sortable1").disableSelection();
});
```

My HTML is.

```
    <ul id="sortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
    <li class="<ui-s></ui-s>tate-default">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ul>
<ul id="sortable1">
    <li class="ui-state-default">1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">5</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">6</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">7</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">8</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">9</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">10</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">11</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">12</li>
</ul>
```

When i remove

```
</ul>
<ul id="sortable1">
```

from this html its work what i want but i want same result with that two different lists. for clear understanding please check http://jsfiddle.net/67hEW/4/

Thanks

Comment: Working example is below in my answer but still problem with float left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have change js to do what i want and its working fine with float left. Js is

```
      (function($){
    $.fn.moveTo = function(selector){
        return this.each(function(){
            var cl = $(this).clone();
            $(cl).appendTo(selector);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    };
    $.fn.moveDown = function(selector){
        return this.each(function(){
            var cl = $(this).clone();
            $(cl).prependTo(selector);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);


  $(function() {
       var oldList, newList, item;
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable1",
        start: function(event, ui) {
            item = ui.item;
            newList = oldList = ui.item.parent();
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {          
            alert("Moved " + item.text() + " from " + oldList.attr('id') + " to " + newList.attr('id'));
            if(oldList.attr('id') ==  newList.attr('id'))
            return;
                $('#'+newList.attr('id')+' li:first-child').moveTo('#'+oldList.attr('id'));

        },
        change: function(event, ui) {  
            if(ui.sender) newList = ui.placeholder.parent();


        },

    });

    $( "#sortable1" ).sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable",
        start: function(event, ui) {
            item = ui.item;
            newList = oldList = ui.item.parent();
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {          
            alert("Moved " + item.text() + " from " + oldList.attr('id') + " to " + newList.attr('id'));
            if(oldList.attr('id') ==  newList.attr('id'))
            return;
                $('#'+newList.attr('id')+' li:last-child').moveDown('#'+oldList.attr('id'));

        },
        change: function(event, ui) {  
            if(ui.sender) newList = ui.placeholder.parent();


        },

    });

    $( "#sortable,#sortable1" ).disableSelection();
  });
```

Working example is on http://jsfiddle.net/67hEW/8/

Answer (score 1):

Sortable connectWith does not work with float. So remove "float:left" and add  "display:inline-block":

```
#sortable li, #sortable1 li {
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
    padding: 1px;
    display:inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 90px;
    font-size: 4em;
    text-align: center;
}
```